# magento CE 1.9 responsive theme - whats its base?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme

Does anyone know what the new responsive theme is based on? e.g. bootstrap, zurb, home grown etc?

Prior to the release i'd been looking hard at the waterlee project (http://waterlee.jakesharp.co/) which is a foundation 5 implementation, but i can't see anything that describes the new rwd theme from a standards\roadmap point of view.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The RWD theme is not based on any frontend framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, etc). Instead, custom styles were written to cater to Magento's markup patterns. Introducing a frontend framework would have required conforming to the patterns of that framework, which would have involved massive refactoring of the template files.

The RWD theme is built using Sass/Compass and various mixins are used to enable more robust style sheet authoring. Additionally there are JavaScript libraries like Enquire.js and modernizr.js that are used by app.js to implement responsive-oriented logic.

Comment: Thanks Erik, i'm liking what you have created TBH. just trying to weigh up the pro's\cons. i'm assuming your approach gives a more lightweight answer vs the waterlee\other approaches that give all the goodies that the framework provides (offcanvas, form field stuff, typeography and cross browser stability). thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

In magento v1.9 they have use **modernizr** 
for more detail about modernizer check this link http://modernizr.com. And please have a look on `skin/frontend/rwd/ folder`